# Flink - Table SQL API - Add a column to a table

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I wonder if there is a way to add a column with constant value to a table in Flink (Java API), something like .withColumn function in Spark DF/DS ?

Regards,
Bastien

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in a Java environment, this can be done with a simple `SELECT` query and registering the resulting `Table` in the catalog.

```
// add constant column
Table withColumn = tEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT a, b, c, 'MyConstant' AS d FROM origTable");
// register new table
tEnv.registerTable("tableWithColumn", withColumn);

// query table with constant column
Table result = tEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM tableWithColumn");
```

The first SQL query in not immediately executed. It is more similar to a view definition that is automatically in-lined and optimized together with the second query before execution.